# apt show to display all possibilities in a screen

Tags: apt

Whenever `apt show lib` typed then followed by tab button twice, the following possibilities will be displayed.

```
user@linux:~$ apt show lib
Display all 24553 possibilities? (y or n)
lib32asan0                                                        libisccfg-export160
lib32asan0-dbg                                                    libisc-export160
lib32asan2                                                        libisc-export169
*... output truncated ...*
lib32asan5-dbg-ppc64-cross                                        libisofs-dev
lib32asan5-dbg-s390x-cross                                        libisofs-doc
lib32asan5-dbg-sparc64-cross                                      libisoparser-java
--More--
```

There are over 20k possibilities, so there is `--More--` option at the end of the page.

Would it be possible to print all these 20k output in a single screen so that I can `grep` the result or redirect it to a file without hitting `spacebar` button many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command instead

`apt-cache search [package name]`

Here use 
`apt-cache search lib`

This shows all the lib packages without the need of hitting space

Hope that helps :)